# Will AIC become smaller when we add more regressors?

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit, aic

As far as I know, AIC's function is similar to $R^2$, which checks fitness of a model.
Will AIC become larger as we simply add more regressors on right hand side of regression? For instance adding $x^2$, $x^3$...

If so, how to determine whether I should include certain covariate in my regression or not?

Comment: Have you visited some of our threads on model building, model selection, and AIC?  You can find them by searching the site: see the form in the upper corner of any page.

Comment: See e.g. wikipedia. AIC includes a penalty for model complexity so the answer is depends on how much the extra regressor adds. If it has little value, AIC may worsen.